# Winding number of composition equaling zero implies existence of complex logarithm

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, winding-number

I have an open and connected set $V$ that is also simply connected. Let $a_1, \ldots, a_n \in V$ and set $U = V \setminus \{a_1, \ldots, a_n\}$. Let $B_{R_i}(a_i)$ be disjoint balls around each $a_i$ so that $\overline{B_{R_i}(a_i)} \subset U$. Let $\gamma_i$ be the circular counterclockwise path along the boundary of each $B_{R_i}(a_i)$ going around once.

Let $f: U \rightarrow \mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$ be holomorphic. Suppose that $n(f\circ \gamma_i; 0) = 0$ where $n(f\circ \gamma_i;0)$ is the winding number of $f\circ \gamma_i$ around $0$. I want to show that $f$ has a logarithm on $U$, i.e. there exists $g: U \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ holomorphic so that $f = e^g$ on $U$.

I know that $n(f\circ \gamma_i; 0) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\gamma_i} \frac{f'}{f}\ dz$, and I've also proven more generally that if $f: U \rightarrow \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$ is holomorphic on an open and connected set $U$ and $\int_{\gamma} \frac{f'}{f}\ dz = 2\pi i n(f\circ \gamma; 0) = 0$ for all piecewise $C^1$ loops $\gamma$ in $U$, then $f$ has a logarithm on $U$.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to use $n(f\circ \gamma_i; 0) =0$ to show that $n(f\circ \gamma; 0) = 0$ for any piecewise $C^1$ loop in $U = V \setminus \{a_1, \ldots, a_n\}$. I feel that $V$ being simply connected will be important so that we can relate $\gamma$ to the $\gamma_i$ by homotopy. I also do not have access to the argument principle for this problem. Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: with respect to your criterion in your 3rd paragraph, the idea is $g:=\frac{f'}{f}$ is analytic in $U$ and the simple loops around $a_i$ form a basis of sorts, so arbitrary $\int_\gamma g $ is equal to an (integer) linear combination of $n\big(f\circ \gamma_i, 0\big)$ i.e. $=0$, by the (invariant) homologous form of Cauchy's Theorem. Artin's criterion for homologous cycles is explicitly winding number based; I would not try to use homotopy.

Comment: @user8675309 Could you elaborate a bit more on how the simple loops around the $a_i$ form a sort of "basis" for loops in $U$? Once I understand this, then everything else falls into place for me. Thanks!

Comment: Please first state your knowledge of the homologous form of Cauchy's Theorem

Comment: @user8675309 The form I learned is: Let $U$ be open and connected and $\Gamma$ be a piecewise $C^1$ cycle in $U$. Let $f$ be holomorphic on $U$. If $\Gamma$ is homologous to $0$ in $U$, i.e. $n(\Gamma; w) = 0$ for all $w \notin U$, then $\int_{\Gamma} f(z) \ dz = 0$.

Comment: that's the relevant portion of the null-homologous form of Cauchy's Theorem; it implies the invariant form that if $\Gamma$ and $\Sigma$ are $C^1$ cycles in a domain $U$ and $n\big(\Gamma, w\big) =n\big(\Sigma, w\big)$ for every $w \not \in U$ then for $g$ analytic in $U$, $\int_{\Gamma}g = \int_{\Sigma}g$. Let $\Sigma$ be an arbitrary $C^1$ cycle in $U$: then $n\big(\Sigma, a_i\big) = m_i$ and $n\big(\Sigma, w\big) = 0$ for $w \notin V$  [simply connected] so let $\Gamma$ be a cycle containing $m_i$ copies of $\gamma_i \implies \int_\Sigma g = \int_\Gamma g = 0$

Comment: @user8675309 That clears everything up. I did learn the invariant form, but it eluded my memory. Thanks!